# How did Kurt Caldwell find out what happened to his son?

Tags: dexter, dexter-new-blood

How could Kurt Caldwell know it was Dexter who killed his son based on the ashes and the metal plate in his son's body?

Sure he could have found out his son was murdered, but how did he come to the conclusion it was Dexter?

Comment: Is the title a spoiler here?  For those who have not reached the point in the season?  If so, can you edit the title?

Comment: This does seem like a plot hole. I don't think it's ever fully explained.

Comment: It's not very well explained (and I would need to get a hold of transcript or watch the episode where Kurt explains it to Dexter), but essentially he remembered the night Dex picked him up, thought about the snow (which were ashes), noticed Dexter came from the incinerator's direction, and went to the incinerator and found the screws...I think given that Kurt is also a seasoned serial killer, he probably has six sense about it, like Dex often does...